# What does "meaner" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not native speaker and now I'm translating a book about women for a male client, named "The Manual: What Women Want and How to Give It to Them". But my client is very picky, so I must translate very correctly. I will give my translation to my client tomorrow, but meet a confusing paragraph. Here is paragraph:

[image]

I've searched for the meaning on Internet and found that "meaner" means "someone who isn't being nice to you, pest", but I don't know whether  it is correct in this paragraph. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: I've never heard ***meaner*** being used as a noun with the sense of *someone who is **mean***, but surely while you were searching the Internet you must have noticed the base / comparative / superlative forms *mean, **meaner,** meanest* (same as *nasty, **nastier,** nastiest*, which would have been equivalent in your context). I think this is "Too Basic", even for ELL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I wondered if the OP got _meaner_ confused with _meanie_, a slang term for someone who is mean.

Answer (score 2):

'Meaner' here implies being 'cruel', but *more* cruel than if she had just made it clear that she wasn't interested.

The suffix 'er' specifies that the second action is *more* cruel.

The reason for the passage in psychological terms is that many, at least on the surface, prefer direct honesty over polite dishonesty. They would rather be shown the respect of a direct refusal, than being lied to, which is why the paragraph describes the action as 'meaner'.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to upvote this answer if you explained _why_ it's considered more cruel to be "polite" than to be direct. As it stands now, this seems more like a clarifying comment than an answer.

Comment: Edited. Any better?

Comment: @mcraen He's probably referring to the fact that by not being upfront in the first place, expectations are unnecessarily raised which creates greater disappointment in the end than if "no" was said in the first place.